# React Admin issue with response data format

Tags: reactjs, node.js, firebase, react-admin

i will try to be as clear as i can. I have a React/Node project and i'm trying to access a ressource in React Admin but i get this error :
`The response to 'getOne' must be like { data: { id: 123, ... } }, but the received data does not have an 'id' key. The dataProvider is probably wrong for 'getOne'`

my controller function :

```
module.exports.getMovieById = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const movie = await movieModel.findById(req.params.id);
        if (!movie) {
            return res.status(404).json({ message: "Movie not found" });
        }

        const responseData = {
            data: {
                id: movie._id.toString(),
                title: movie.title,
                position: movie.position,
                image: movie.image,
                song: movie.song.toString(),
            },
        };

        console.log('response data ' , responseData)

        res.status(200).json(responseData);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).json({ message: "Internal server error" });
    }
    };
```

the responseData :

```
response data  {
          data: {
            id: '6581bde69dcf54c00c57dc46',
            title: 'movie title',
            position: '1',
            image: 'link',
            song: '6581adf30894b8f4b251b53a'
          }
    }
```

The data is the same i have in my database and the same i retrieve from postman when i manually type the url for the getOne so it might be an issue with React Admin and not the backend but i cannot figure what is going on here.
I can give more details if needed i'm not sure what else you might need to know to help me.

Comment: How is this a firebase question?

Comment: What dataProvider are you using? Can you debug the return value of the `dataProvider.getOne()` call?